# How does ServiceNameQuery work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, there is a following piece of code:

```
$scope.posts = Post.query({ user_id: $stateParams.user_id })
```

How does this construction work? When JS execute this line posts may be empty, but after some time server side will return some posts and my view will render a lot of posts. But how 'query' function may return value in future? I don't understand it, because AJAX call is asynchronous, and I don't send any value in any function. Please, describe this moment. Thanks.

I know about promises and $q, but I don't understand how it works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally it executes an asynchrnous operation and returns a reference to an empty array.

When the asynchronous operation has finished it will populate that array with elements.

`$scope.posts` is a reference to the same array, containing those elements.

Simple example implementation:

```
app.factory('Post', function ($timeout) {

  var query = function (selector) {

    var result = [];

    // An asynchronous operation
    $timeout(function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        result.push({ id: i });
      }
    }, 3000);

    return result;
  };

  return {
    query: query
  };
});
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/t6yRNFnHcrQ1X2HCmXjb?p=preview